# Control whether session timestamp is updated

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

In my application, which runs with Spring Web MVC on Tomcat 7.0, I have certain controllers where, although requests to them will require authentication and a valid session, I don't want the session's expiration timestamp to be updated. In other words, I want the session to expire exactly when it would have had this particular HTTP request not happened.

These are AJAX methods if it matters, though I don't know if it does.

Can this be done through either generic Java EE or some special Tomcat hooks? Is there another way to achieve this? I know about http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#setMaxInactiveInterval%28int%29 but that seems like almost the opposite of what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<del>*Access* time is updated **only** when the session is [being accessed by](https://github.com/apache/tomcat70/blob/trunk/java/org/apache/catalina/connector/Request.java#L2908) `HttpServletRequest#getSession`. So if you make sure you are not tampering with the session, you should be OK.</del> **UPDATE:** based on [the JavaDoc](https://github.com/apache/tomcat70/blob/trunk/java/org/apache/catalina/Session.java#L268) the above is not true (even thou I searched the source code thoroughly and didn't find any piece of code responsible for such behavior).

On the other hand, if you need to access the session in your AJAX request, you are pretty much screwed. The only solution I can think of is to store `lastAccessTime` manually (e.g. in servlet filter) and then check session timeout and [invalidate the session manually](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#invalidate%28%29) (e.g. in the same filter). That should be pretty straightforward and easy to implement.

---

**UPDATE:** Just for the fun I've implemented the filter (not tested):

```
public class SessionInvalidationFilter implements Filter {

    private static final String LAST_ACCESS_SESSION_ATTR = "lastAccessTime";

    private static final long SESSION_TIMEOUT = 1000 * 60 * 20; // 20 minutes

    private static final String IGNORE_ACCESS_URI = "/this/will-not/update/access-time";

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        // Cast to HTTP request and response
        HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        // Check if we are handling standard request
        if (!IGNORE_ACCESS_URI.equals(httpRequest.getRequestURI())) {
            chain.doFilter(new SessionAccessAwareRequest(httpRequest), response);
            return;
        }
        // Now we can handle the special case of non-tracked request
        boolean expired = false;
        HttpSession session = httpRequest.getSession(false);
        if (session == null) {
            // No session means the AJAX contained no or incorrect JSESSIONID
            expired = true;
        } else {
            Long lastAccessTime = (Long) session.getAttribute(LAST_ACCESS_SESSION_ATTR);
            if (lastAccessTime == null || lastAccessTime + SESSION_TIMEOUT < System.currentTimeMillis()) {
                session.invalidate(); // Invalidate manually
                expired = true;
            }
        }
        // Handle error or process normally
        if (expired) {
            httpResponse.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }

    private static class SessionAccessAwareRequest extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {

        public SessionAccessAwareRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
            super(request);
        }

        @Override
        public HttpSession getSession() {
            return getSession(true);
        }

        @Override
        public HttpSession getSession(boolean create) {
            HttpSession session = super.getSession(create);
            if (session != null) {
                session.setAttribute(LAST_ACCESS_SESSION_ATTR, System.currentTimeMillis());
            }
            return session;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I can't find any `access` method in [`HttpSession`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#method_summary) interface.

Comment: By the way, every time you send a request to the server, the remaining session expire time *resets* (even when using ajax calls).

Comment: `access` is internal catalina method, which is not from servlet specification (check the GitHub link in my answer). The last *access time* is being updated probably because your application is accessing the session without your knowledge (e.g. spring security or some other component).

Comment: And by the way I've added sample filter implementation to my answer.

Comment: And the correct link to Catalina's `access` method declaration - https://github.com/apache/tomcat70/blob/trunk/java/org/apache/catalina/Session.java#L268 , where the JavaDoc is contradicting the first paragraph of my answer... so you are probably right that this is being always updated (even thou I did search through the source code thoroughly).

Comment: If using a StandardManager, then it should be as "simple" as getting the manager from the ServletContext, and then using the manager's findSession(request.getRequestedSessionId()).   If using PersistentManager,  or a manager that extends PersistentManagerBase, then it gets tricky.  PersistentManagerBase's findSession and swapIn will hit the session's access() and endAccess() methods.  Either implement your own PersistentManager and override findSession/swapIn, or go crazy with reflection.

Answer (score 4):

No.
Before Spring and your application have a chance to handle the HTTP request coming from the browser of the current user, the current user's session has been renewed by tomcat according to Servlet specification. So Spring and your application have no way to control renewing the current user's session.

The "7.6 Last Accessed Times" of servlet-3_1-final.pdf says "The
the session is considered to be accessed when a request that is part of the session is first handled by the Servlet container."

If Tomcat is the Servlet container.

When `Request.getSession()` or `getSession(boolean create)` are called:
See
[Line 2955 of Request.java](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/62a684cd2b2039a68e74813cf4e20fc95a2cebe4/java/org/apache/catalina/connector/Request.java#L2955)
and
[Line 269 of Session.java](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/62a684cd2b2039a68e74813cf4e20fc95a2cebe4/java/org/apache/catalina/Session.java#L269)

It is said

```java
“/**
* Update the accessed time information for this session.  This method
* should be called by the context when a request comes in for a particular
* session, even if the application does not reference it.
*/“
```

The related implemented class [Line 675 of StandardSession.java](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/62a684cd2b2039a68e74813cf4e20fc95a2cebe4/java/org/apache/catalina/session/StandardSession.java#L675)
Once  `Request.getSession()` or `getSession(boolean create)` is called the existing session is renewed by update the `thisAccessedTime`

Shared a debug process to see where the existing session is renewed with

- Tomcat 9.0.38 (not deployed in a cluster)
- Spring framework version 4.3.12.RELEASE
- Spring-security version 4.2.4.RELEASE
- Servlet 3.1

Operations:

1. Login the application, so now the current user's session already exists.
2. Enable the breakpoint on [Line 686 of StandardSession.java](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/9.0.38/java/org/apache/catalina/session/StandardSession.java#L686)
3. Click any UI button to trigger an HTTP request.

See [Line 511 of org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/9.0.38/java/org/apache/catalina/authenticator/AuthenticatorBase.java#L511)
refer https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMQPl.jpg it shows the logic as

- find the session by the session ID in the request headers 'Cookie:
  JSESSIONID'
- check if the session is still valid by calculating `timeNow - thisAccessedTime`
- if current user session is still valid then update the `thisAccessedTime` with access time.
  This is the first place and the only place where the session is renewed

After that the following call on this method will not call access(), this can be seen when

continue the HTTP request handling progress,  in [Line 541 of org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/9.0.38/java/org/apache/catalina/authenticator/AuthenticatorBase.java#L541) filter chain processing
[Line 110 of org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.java](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/4.2.4.RELEASE/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/context/HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.java#L110)
and [Line 130 of org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.java](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/4.2.4.RELEASE/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/session/ConcurrentSessionFilter.java#L130)
see https://i.stack.imgur.com/SsY7j.jpg

Only Tomcat who can control the updating `thisAccessedTime`  to renew the existing session valid time.

### Resolution

Actually the objective is to achieve an effect looks like some special HTTP requests (some special APIs, URLs) can not renew the on line user' session, As a result, if only these APIs call are left, there is no more other normal APIs call appear over a period of valid session interval, then invalidate the session.

Need trade-off according to your scenarios before select one of the following options

A> Find a cutpoint, options can be

1. A customized implementation of `javax.servlet.Fitler` at the
   end of the filter chain of Servlet context
2. A customized implementation of
   `org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBean` at the end of the
   filter chain of Sprint internal Filter chain.
3. A customized implementation of
   `org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerInterceptor`

Then

- for normal API call: record a customized session attribute
  `thisAccessedTime`
- for special API call:  check if the session is still valid with session attribute `thisAccessedTime`. if it is expired  then invalidate the session

B> A customized Filter implementation of `javax.servlet.Fitler` at the end of the filter chain of Servlet context
Wraper the `Request.getSession()` and `getSession(boolean create)` with a completely customized session life circle and session event implementation.

C> Websocket and Long Polling for real-time communication

Comment: Thanks for all the research. Notwithstanding, I'm a bit confused. According to your writeup, tomcat is the only one who can update the thisAccessedTime but the writeup also says if you do a request.getSession() the current session is renwed by updating the thisAccessedTime. request.getSession is (generally)called inside java controller. Does this call go back to tomcat code so that tomcat can update the thisAccessedTime  and return to the next line from the java code?