# How to allow some requests to bypass session timeout in web.xml

Tags: java, spring, timeout, session-timeout

A webapp that we support is written in JAVA using SpringMVC.
We have an existing requirement that our application times-out after 60 minutes of user inactivity.
To achieve this, we have a **session-timeout** entry in the applications **web.xml** file; until now, this worked just fine.

The problem is that now we have a new GUI component which needs to call home at regular intervals (*60 seconds*).
This is basically acting as a keep-alive :(
Due to browser versions that we have to support, we can't use websockets so we're just polling at regular intervals (*I'm not sure if this is relevant*).

Is there a way to configure our webapp to omit specific requests from triggering the **session-timeout**.

Answer (score -1):

You can try [session.setMaxInactiveInterval](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#setMaxInactiveInterval%28int%29). This should override the default timeout.

Comment: The problem is that we still need the session to timeout after 60 minutes we just don't want specific automatic intermittent calls to trigger a keep-alive.
Basically, our users leave their web browsers open when they do something else. If they don't interact with the app for 60 mins, it times them out. But these specific REST calls are automatically run every 60 seconds (or so) and those calls can't keep the session alive.

Comment: Oooh. I get it. I dont know any configuration off hand, but you could manually calculate and set the max inactive interval for the requests that you don't want to reset the session timeout. For example, 'session.setMaxInactiveInterval(60 minutes - (current time - last accessed time))' . Make sense? You could implement this in a Filter. Checkout this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19191668/control-whether-session-timestamp-is-updated). It seems related to what you are asking.

Comment: The route that I think we'll have to go is to only make those automatic calls when there is user activity in the GUI.